# Volume on my HDD accessible, but files inaccessible

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

I'm facing weird problem with one of the volumes on my hard disk.

Volume D: is showing 0 bytes in properties, whereas I am able to enter the drive and folders but not able to access the files. Screenshot - http://prntscr.com/1rlh8y

Volume's status shows fine in Disk management - http://prntscr.com/1rliad

Operating system is Windows XP SP3. Please help.

Edit: Adding screenshot of my attempt to bring it online, please note reactivate option is inactive in disk management.

[image]

Comment: Additional info:

I was checking properties of all the drives altogether, clicked on security tab. It hung there, so I closed that properties window. After that it became inaccessible.

I also tried checking the volume and removing the drive letter too, nothing changed.

Comment: Are you able to access the files when the HDD is installed in another PC?

Comment: I do not have another PC to test with :( I had similar problem earlier when I installed XP afresh, but that time all the drives of this 1 TB HDD were deactivated. So I simply went to disk management and activated them. This time it's showing this D: already active and hence not giving any option to deactivate. I also disabled and enabled HDD, didn't help.

Comment: Earlier today, I noticed same problem was in another drive on my PC. That drive happens to have Windows 7 installed in it. I logged in via Windows 7 to check if drives are accessible there. Turns out, only system directories (windows, user profile, etc.) are accessible and I cannot even open system drive of Windows 7. Also, in this installation I cannot open D: at all.

Comment: `DiskPart could not online the selected disk.` ¬_¬

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

For some reason, Windows had removed ownership of all the files which in turn made files inaccessible whereas I was able to access drive and folders.